# ¿Por qué la función get.Day() me returnea un valor nulo y la función get.Month() un valor no exacto?

Tags: javascript, html

estoy intentando hacer un sistema de recuperación de fecha a través de JavaScript, concretamente haciendo uso de la función `Date`. El problema es que me returnea valores inexactos cuando intenta pillarlos de manera individual (valor nulo o NaN con get.Day y el mes de Marzo en vez de el de Abril), dejo aquí mi código, saludos.

HTML:

```
<span class="a-text-bold" id="fechade"></span>
```

JS:

```
var fecha = new Date();
var month = fecha.getMonth();
console.log(month);

var spanish_months = [
    'Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'

];
var days = [
    '28', '30', '31'
];
if(month == '1'){
    var news = spanish_months[0];
} else if(month == '2'){
    var news = spanish_months[1]; 
}
if(month == '3'){
    var news = spanish_months[2];
}
if(month == '4'){
    var news = spanish_months[3];
}
if(month == '5'){
    var news = spanish_months[4];
}
if(month == '6'){
    var news = spanish_months[5];
}
if(month == '7'){
    var news = spanish_months[6];
}
if(month == '8'){
    var news = spanish_months[7];

}
if(month == '9'){
    var news = spanish_months[8];
}
if(month == '10'){
    var news = spanish_months[9];
}
if(month == '11'){
    var news = spanish_months[10];
}
if(month == '12'){
    var news = spanish_months[11];
}

var day = fecha.getDay();
console.log(fecha.getDay);
if(days.includes(day)){

}else{
    var result = parseInt(day) + parseInt(2);
    var porst = result+' '+'de'+' '+news;
    var span_envio = document.getElementById('fechade');
    span_envio.innerHTML = porst;
   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## getDay()

Según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

> El método `getDay()` devuelve el día de la semana de la fecha especificada en función de la fecha local; siendo 0 (Domingo) el
> primer día.

Es decir, la función `getDay()` como máximo va a devolverte 6, no el día del mes, para obtener el día que estás buscando debes emplear la función `getDate()`

## getDate()

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)

> El método `getDate()` devuelve el día del mes para la fecha especificada
> de acuerdo con la hora local.

## getMonth()

Siguiendo el texto de la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

> El método `getMonth()` devuelve el mes del objeto Date según la hora
> local, donde el número cero indica el primer mes del año.

Es decir, si numeramos a los meses como estamos habituados, debemos agregarle uno a lo que retorna esa función para obtener el número que buscamos. Todos hemos caído en esta situación en alguna vez con JavaScript.

## Cambios

Lo bueno es que todo el código del mes lo puedes resumir en

```
var news = spanish_months[month];
```

Y debes cambiar las líneas

```
var day = fecha.getDay();
var porst = result+' '+'de'+' '+news;
```

por

```
var day = fecha.getDate();
var porst = day+' '+'de'+' '+news;
```

respectivamente

Comment: No te voy a mentir, una respuesta muy bien elaborada con una explicación sencilla y a su vez adjuntando la documentación, simplemente perfecto. Me has sacado del apuro, ¡muchas gracias! :D

Comment: Siempre un gusto ayudar, si alguien dice que nunca tuvo problemas por causa del `getMonth()` que tire la primera piedra :P